# how to play second element in SerialElement?

Tags: actionscript-3, media-player, osmf

I have a SerialElement with two MediaElements and I want to jump in second element after I click the next button.

Answer (score 0):

From [`SerialElement` documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/org/osmf/elements/SerialElement.html):

> The only way that the "current" status can pass from one child to another is when the state of one of the current child's traits changes in such a way that the SerialElement knows that it needs to change its current child. For example, if each child in the sequence has the PlayTrait, the "current" status advances from one child to the next when a child finishes playing and its PlayTrait's PlayState property changes from PLAYING to STOPPED.

So you can force the current child's state to change:

```
(serialElement.currentChild.getTrait("PlayTrait") as PlayTrait).stop();
```